# Using Active Directory Groups setting up SQL Server permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an issue with my SQL Server 2008 R2 permissions setup. My server is running on Windows 2008 R2.

I have created 3 groups in Active Directory and assigned each group a certain set of permissions within SQL Server. The groups that I have are `RPDSQLADM` which is assigned the `sysadmin` role; `RPDSQLDEV` which is assigned `dbcreator` role; and `RPDSQLUSER` which is assigned the `public` role.

The issue that I have is that anyone assigned to the `RPDSQLDEV` group and create and delete databases, but cannot attach databases. I do not want the developers to have `sysadmin` access. What can I do to allow them to be able to attach databases without granting sysadmin access?

Answer (score 0):

Attaching databases requires the following permissions:

CREATE DATABASE, CREATE ANY DATABASE, or ALTER ANY DATABASE

[Attach A Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190209(v=sql.110).aspx)